# Laravel login use make:auth

Tags: laravel

i have some problems with authentication using **php artisan make:auth** . Register is successfully. But if i want to login. It can't login to dashboard/home page. It back to index. When i check at network console in browser, status show 302 found.

This is my RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Band;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Session;
use File;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Register Controller
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
 | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
 | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
 |
 */

use RegistersUsers;

/ **
* Where to redirect users after registration.
*
* @var string
*/
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
* Create a new controller instance.
*
* @return void
*/
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */

 /**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
 protected function create(array $data, Request $request)
 {

 }
 protected function showFormRegister(){
  return view('auth.register');
 }







 protected function store(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
    'Name' => 'required|string',
    'UserName' => 'required',
    'Email' =>'required|unique:users',
    'Password' => 'required|min:6',
    'ConfirmPassword' => 'required|same:Password',
    'CategoryType' => 'required'
]);
$user = new User;
$user->username = $request->input('UserName');
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('Password'));
    $user->email = $request->input('Email');
    $user->name = $request->input('Name');
    $user->user_type = $request->input('CategoryType');

    $user->save();


    return redirect()->to('/')->with('message','register successfully');   
  }


  }
```

my login page view

```
<form id="popup_login_form" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="text" name="Username" id="login_username"  value="username" placeholder="username">
                    @if ($errors->has('Username'))<span> <strong>{{ $errors->first('Username') }}</strong></span> @endif
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="login_password"  value="password" placeholder="password">
                    @if ($errors->has('Password'))<span> <strong>{{ $errors->first('Password') }}</strong></span> @endif
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="buttonLogin">

                </form><!-- login form -->
```

My **LoginController.php**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 class LoginController extends Controller
 {
   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Login Controller
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
   | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
   | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
   |
   */

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected function redirectTo() {
    if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') {
        return '/admin/home';
    }
    if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'band'){
        return '/band/home';
    }

}

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}



public function username()
{
return 'username';
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'Username' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
    }

}
```

My migration **Users**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->enum('user_type', ['customer', 'band', 'admin'])- 
        >default('customer');
        $table->string('profile_picture')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('last_login')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
           });
    }

     /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

My model **User**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','username'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

protected $table = "users";

// Ambil data dari field yang bersangkutan
public function detail() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\\'.ucfirst($this->user_type));
}
 }
```

My route web.php

```
<?php



 Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@testFunction');

 Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('welcome'); 
 });

    //Auth::routes();

    //Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

   Route::get('/band/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

   Route::group(['prefix'=>'register'], function(){
   Route::get('/v1','Auth\RegisterController@showFormRegister');
   Route::post('/store','Auth\RegisterController@store');

 });
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your `redirectTo()` method is not being called. You can use `authenticated()` method in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` (just change your `protected function redirectTo()` to `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)`)

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'role' => 'admin', 'password' => $request->password])) {
return redirect('dashboard');
} else if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'role' => 'guest', 'password' => $request->password])) {
return redirect('/');
} else {
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Email Atau Password Anda Salah']);
}